# find in list and remove text

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have example data

```
jkjkjkMr James Jon
lrtrtrMiss Krin Poo
erere\Mrs Lolo Freh
```

I want cut string behind Mr, Miss, Mrs

```
text[text.find('Mr')]
>> Mr James Jon

text[text.find('Miss')]
>> Miss Krin Poo

text[text.find('Mrs')]
>> Mrs Lolo Freh
```

But I don't want find line by line, how can I loop?

```
ls = ['Mr', 'Miss', 'Mrs']

text[text.find(ls)]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "But I don't want find line by line, how can I loop?", could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is the type of your input?
are you reading from a file? is it just a plain text variable? is it a dataframe?

Answer (score -1):

**Code**

```
s = ['jkjkjkMr James Jon','lrtrtrMiss Krin Poo', 'erere\Mrs Lolo Freh']
print(s)
new_s = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    if 'Mr' or 'Miss' or 'Mrs' in s[i]:
        new_s.append(s[i][s[i].find('M'):])
print(new_s)
```

**Output**

```
['jkjkjkMr James Jon', 'lrtrtrMiss Krin Poo', 'erere\\Mrs Lolo Freh']
['Mr James Jon', 'Miss Krin Poo', 'Mrs Lolo Freh']
```